# Device logs for bluetooth on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, bluetooth

I am currently developing an iPhone app that pairs with a **bluetooth** device.

We are having some latency issues regarding this pairing, and detecting at the correct time when our device is paired/connected.

Do you guys know if the iPhone has some `log` information we can look at/extract for **bluetooth** devices?

Comment: You mean traces from the iOS BT-stack in some kind of verbose mode, or just timestamps from within your app to pinpoint what takes time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try generating a [Bluetooth diagnostic log](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ios/bluetooth/), that's the most info you will get (without jail breaking).
If you need more info, a Bluetooth sniffer/protocol analyzer may be needed.

Comment: How can you get more logs with Jailbreaking the phone?

Comment: From a shell I use `keychain_dumper` to get link keys for BT connections, so an air sniffer can decrypt the connection. I've never done it for BLE but I assume the same thing is possible. Also you can watch the BT diagnostic logs and console log in real time (just `tail -f`)

Comment: @Brendan Shanks When you say "bluetooth diagnostic log" do you mean the main system_logs.logarchive file, or are there more specific Bluetooth-related files?